# Python Error Logging to Check for Duplicate Rows and Duplicate Columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, exception

The following code reads an existing MS Excel spreadsheet, creates a column map, then exports results to another Excel spreadsheet.  The sheet and associated columns are actually much larger, but to keep the context simple I have paired down the number of columns in the map.

You will note that in the process I am creating 2 NULL columns and dropping any duplicate rows.  I am struggling with a proper Try: Except: statement(s) that will validate that I am not overwriting existing columns with the created NULL columns, and to validate that are no duplicate rows.  I know that I am not, but need the error log report for audit purposes.  Following is a simple mock up of the code, this is as far as I have gotten.  I am still fairly new to exception handling and would appreciate your help.  Thanks in advance.

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(levelname)-5.5s]  %(message)s",
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()])

os.chdir(r'M:\Loans')

col_map = {'Loan #' : 'LoanNo',
           'Last Name' : 'LastName',
           'Purchase Price' : 'PurchasePrice',
           'Loan Amt' : 'LoanAmt',
           'Property Address' : 'PropertyAddress',
           'City' : 'City',
           'State' : 'State',
           'Zip Code' : 'ZipCode',
           'Interest Rate' : 'InterestRate',
           'UPBCurrent' : 'UPBCurrent',               
           'NextDueDateAtPurchase' : 'NextDueDateAtPurchase',
           'CurrentAdvanceRate': 'CurrentAdvanceRate',
           'Comments' : 'Comments',
           'CurrentAdvanceAmount': 'CurrentAdvanceAmount',
           'SecondRoundCurrentAdvanceRate' : 'SecRoundCurrentAdvRate', 
           'SecondRoundCurrentAvanceAmount' : 'SecRoundCurrentAdvAmount', 
           }

for f in os.listdir():

    logging.info('Reading in file {}'.format(f))

df=pd.read_excel('M:\Loans\Loan Blotter XYZ OLD.xlsx')

df['UPBCurrent'] = None
df['NextDueDateAtPurchase'] = None

df = df[col_map.keys()]
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.columns = [col_map[col] for col in df.columns]
df['Channel'] = 'Whole Loans'
df['DateCreated'] = datetime.today().date()
df.to_excel(r'M:\Err Log.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to check that you won't overwrite existing cols:

```py
null_cols = ['UPBCurrent', 'UPBCurrent']
for null_col in null_cols:
    if null_col in df.columns:
        logging.error("{} will be overwritten.".format(null_col))
    else:
        logging.info("Adding null column {}.".format(null_col))
        df[null_col] = None
```

to check that drop duplicates will work:

```py
try:
    df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
except:
    logging.error("Failed to drop duplicate rows.")
```

Comment: Worked Perfect.  Thank you.